# How to create a RESTful MeteorJS application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, http, meteor

I've been banging my head against this issue for some day now. Even posted two questions here about specific packages ([iron-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535969/post-from-ruby-to-meteor-with-iron-router), [Restivus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581774/configuring-restivus-post-method-for-meteor)) but I have not been successful.

My case is this: I have a Meteor JS application that must receive http POST calls to insert a record in it's MongoDB database, but I've been unable to get past the connection between MeteorJS and the rest of the world.

I've tried iron-router, Restivus, and as of a few hours ago, Picker. I've followed the [REST API](http://meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API#iron-router%20server-side%20routes) examples at Meteorpedia with no prevail.

Using Restivus, I got the following code:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    //Must exist, but all options can be empty
    Restivus.configure({
    });

    //Allow Restivus to manage Reports
    Restivus.addCollection('reports', {
        routeOptions: {},
    });

    console.log("Inside 'isServer'");

    Restivus.addRoute('reports/:message', {

        // POST
        post: {
            action: function(){

                console.log("Got to post!");

                var response = null;
                var message = this.urlParams.message;

                if(message){
                    console.log("Message received: " + message);
                    return {status: "success", data: message};
                } else {
                    console.log("Message empty...");
                    return {status: "fail", message: "Post not found"};
                }

                //Response to caller
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And with Picker, I got this:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){

    Picker.route('/newReport/:message'), function(params, req, res, rext){

        if(req.method == "POST")
            console.log("Got a POST");
        else
            console.log("Not a POST");

        res.end("Returned");
    }
}
```

In both attempts, I get the same result when making a GET call. I always get what seems to be the HTML code of an empty template with full `<head>` but empty `<body>` tags. I get the same result when I try GET and POST methods to any path within the webapp.

Since the error is the same on both cases, I am assuming at one point of my routing I am making my mistake, so here follows the rest of `server/router.js`:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    waitOn: function(){
        return [Meteor.subscribe('reports')]
    }
});

//Page of the report
Router.route('/report/:message', {
    name: 'reportPage',
    data: function(){
        return Reports.findOne(this.params.message);
    }
})

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'reportList'
});

<<REST code goes here>>
```

I suspect that at one point the router is sending a blank page, but I cannot see anything in the router info that implies this.

I even tried to do an if/else statement that separates everything in the client, and everything in the server, but it made no difference. I'll try to keep updating as a continue testing.

Thank you in advance!

Note: I tried both GET and POST methods using curl, a small Ruby script that I made, and REST Console. The result was the same in all 3 instances.

Comment: Did you check out https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-rest/?

Comment: I've seen it, but I haven't tried it. Honestly, I'm a bit confused on how it works, and could not find a working example of it.

Comment: I've left a comment here explaining what was wrong with your Restivus implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581774/configuring-restivus-post-method-for-meteor. Sorry that you had so much difficulty getting your REST API setup in Meteor. What did you ultimately use?

Answer (score 0):

What about using Iron-Router's server-side routes?

```
Router
.route('/api/path', {where: 'server'})
.post(function ()
{
    var req = this.request.body;
});
```